# How to check mobile internet connection

Tags: javascript, cordova, internet-connection

I have to call two functions **based** on internet/connection availability.

If there is internet connection **present** then call insert function, otherwise call update.

I tried like this:

```
var online = window.navigator.onLine;
    if (online==ture) {
        alert('connection down.');
    }else
    {
      alert('Please check your internet connection and try again');
    }
```

This code works in browser only but not on device.It always shows `alert('connection down');` in both cases i.e. internet is present or not.

Please guide on this code as I am new to Phonegap.

Comment: online=true? not ture?

Comment: @MidhunMundayadan i tried as you said but my mobile don't have internet but when i print online variable it's showing true Please help me

Comment: @MidhunMundayadan YES we developeing  one phoneGap application now we need device check internet connection

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin to achieve your needs
(https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information). After installing, try this code to check the internet connection.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready",checkInternet,false);
function checkInternet(){
   if(navigator.connection.type=="none"){
     //no internet connection
     alert("No connection");    
    }else{
     alert("Connection ok");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's part of the HTML5 API. Check the value of window.navigator.onLine -- it will be false if the user is offline.
an indicator is updated as the browser goes online and offline.

```
   <head>
   <title>Online status</title>
   <script>
   function updateIndicator() 
   {
     document.getElementById('indicator').textContent = navigator.onLine ? 'online' : 'offline';
   }
   </script>
   </head>
   <body onload="updateIndicator()" ononline="updateIndicator()" onoffline="updateIndicator()">
   <p>The network is: <span id="indicator">(state unknown)</span>
  </body>
```

[For more info](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#browser-state)

Comment: thanks but code will be work on Browser when run this code in Mobile it's not working

Answer (score 0):

The API you are using will **not** work on mobile. You need to use [Network API](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information/blob/master/doc/index.md) instead.

You need to do:

1. Add network plugin using below command via CL

   `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.network-information`
2. Now get network status as

   ```
   function checkConnection() {

       var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
       var states = {};

       states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
       states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
       states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
       states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
       states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
       states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
       states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
       states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

       alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
   }
   checkConnection();
   ```